# WordPress WP_Query - Query parent pages only

Tags: wordpress

I'm using a WP_Query to query my custom post type posts. This custom post type has parent and children pages. I'm trying to pull the first parent page. How would I do this?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

```
$parent_only_query = new WP_Query(array(
    'post_type' => 'my-custom-post-type',
    'post_parent' => 0
));

while ($parent_only_query->have_posts()){
    $parent_only_query->the_post();
    // etc...
}

wp_reset_query(); // if you're not in your main loop! otherwise you can skip this
```

Comment: Is there a way to exclude the first page from the loop?

Comment: Figured it out! Using `'offset' => 1` and `'posts_per_page' => 999` from this thread: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/219540/wp-query-offset-argument-does-not-work/#answer-219543

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this functionality by making a query to database;

```
<?php

$parent_posts= $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT ID, post_title FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_parent=0 AND post_type='page' AND post_status='publish' ORDER BY menu_order ASC" );

foreach($parent_posts as $record){ ?>

    <a href="<?php echo get_permalink($record->ID) ?>" >
        <h1><?php echo $record->post_title; ?></h1>
    </a>
    <p><?php echo $record->post_title;?></p>

<?php } ?>
```

*Note:- `$wpdb` is global variable.*

Answer (score 1):

Once you have run your query and you are looping through it, you can access the ID of the parent of each post with `$post->post_parent`, and if that is not null you can get that post content with `get_post()`:

```
<?php
if($post->post_parent):
    $parent = get_post($post->post_parent);
?>
<h2><?=$parent->post_title;?></h2>
<p><?=$parent->post_content;?></p>
<?php
endif;
?>
```